# Is a high `min_replan_interval` a good idea for a low traffic app?

Tags: neo4j

We have an app with a Neo4j backend that receives a relatively low amount of traffic, max a few hundred hits per hour. I'm wondering if the default value of 1 second for `dbms.cypher.min_replan_interval` will mean that all our query plans will be replanned between calls and whether we might see better performance if we increased it.

Also, are there any dangers to increasing this? If the structure of our data doesn't change all that much will it not then be a good idea to keep the query plans for as long as possible?

Comment: Shouldn't your question actually be ... "We are seeing performance issues with our queries" ... followed by the queries that take too long ? I'm just asking because fiddling with these settings if your performance is fine is strange (and the benefits would be relatively low) ...

Comment: Not really since we're not talking about specific queries. There's no doubt that we could find performance gains in query tuning, but my doubt is whether the standard value for the replan interval is optimized for high volume apps and if we should change it since we're using Neo4j in an environment that experiences less traffic than it was designed for.